# C++/WinAPI - Removing a flag from a DWORD (bitwise operator?)

Tags: c++, winapi, bit-manipulation, flags, dword

I now know how to check if there is a certain flag in a DWORD (Specifically a Windows style) by using the bitwise `&` AND operator. How would I do this:

```
if (dwMyFlags & dwSomeFlag) {
    // dwMyFlags contains dwSomeFlag
    // ->> How do I remove dwSomeFlag from dwMyFlags?
}
```

I know subtracting it wouldn't work, is there some operator that can remove flags from a DWORD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the flag is set you can use exclusive or to unset:

```
dwMyFlags ^= dwSomeFlag;
```

If you are unsure of the state of the flag, you need to use bitwise &, and bitwise not ~

```
dwMyFlags &= ~dwSomeFlag;
```

Comment: +1 Great, the second method saves me from writing another if-statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Do a bitwise `&` with the *inverse* of the flag that you want:

```
dwMyFlags = dwMyFlags & ~dwSomeFlag;
```

You can abbreviate this using `&=`:

```
dwMyFlags &= ~dwSomeFlag;
```

Comment: +1 for inverse, and differentiating the abbreviation and full-form.

Answer (score 5):

AND with the bits that are not part of that flag:

```
dwMyFlags &= ~dwSomeFlag;
```

This is scalable to removing multiple flags as well:

```
dwMyFlags &= ~(dwSomeFlag | dwSomeOtherFlag);
```

Also, Hungarian notation has outlived its use.

Comment: +1 for example of removing multiple flags. Also, I know, I never use it, I just felt like doing it for the sake of the example. I usually give my variables short-but-descriptive names. Hungarian notation makes code look ugly to me.

Comment: @BrandonMiller, It was a lot more useful when you didn't have a method to check what type it was in a second within wanting to know.

Comment: Yes, with Visual Assist X I can just hover over a variable to see its type.